# Why does it print <p> when doing this Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to print some content formatted in HTML but it just prints the code

```
<td>{{ html_entity_decode($p->content) }}</td>
```

This code prints this: `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur quidem alias fugit hic incidunt consequuntur quasi fuga tenetur sit perferendis nisi dignissimos accusantium ab expedita temporibus velit dolorum, ipsam explicabo</p>`

Any idea? Without html_entity_decode it's even worse.

Comment: $p->content probably is responsible for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling blade to escape it and so it prints the actual HTML, including the `<p>` tags.  You have stored the HTML tags within `$p->content`.

To fix, use the unescaped blade syntax:

```
<td>{!! $p->content !!}</td>
```